# AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'get_params' while deploying

Tags: python, flask, web-deployment

My model has been saved and I'm trying to deploy the model but I'm getting the error message AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'get_params'. I am not able to find any error in my code. Can anyone help to solve this problem. Thanks in advance for your help. My complete code can be seen below.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from datetime import date
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import pickle
app=Flask(__name__)
model=pickle.load(open('XGBoost.pkl','rb'))
@app.route('/',methods=['GET'])

def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
def predict():
if request.method=='POST':
    loan_amt=float(request.form['loan_amt'])
    term=int(request.form['term'])
    issue_d=str(request.form['issue_d'])
    tol_paymnt=float(request.form['tol_paymnt'])
    int_recvd=float(request.form['int_recvd'])
    late_recv_fee=float(request.form['total_rec_late_fee'])
    rcvry=float(request.form['rcvry'])
    lst_pymnt_d=str(request.form['lst_pymnt_d'])
    last_pymnt_amnt=float(request.form['last_pymnt_amnt'])
    last_credit_pull_d=str(request.form['last_credit_pull_d'])
    nxt_pymnt_d=str(request.form['nxt_pymnt_d'])

    df=pd.DataFrame([[loan_amt,term,issue_d,tol_paymnt,int_recvd,late_recv_fee,rcvry,lst_pymnt_d,last_pymnt_amnt,last_credit_pull_d,nxt_pymnt_d]],
            columns=('loan_amnt','term','issue_d','total_pymnt','total_rec_int','late_recv_fee','recoveries','last_pymnt_d','last_pymnt_amnt','last_credit_pull_d','nxt_pymnt_d'))

    df['issue_d']=pd.to_datetime(df['issue_d']).dt.date
    df['last_pymnt_d']=pd.to_datetime(df['last_pymnt_d']).dt.date
    df['last_credit_pull_d']=pd.to_datetime(df['last_credit_pull_d']).dt.date
    df['nxt_pymnt_d']=pd.to_datetime(df['nxt_pymnt_d']).dt.date

    df['issue_d']=round((date.today()-df['issue_d'])/np.timedelta64(1,'M'))
    df['last_pymnt_d']=round((date.today()-df['last_pymnt_d'])/np.timedelta64(1,'M'))
    df['last_credit_pull_d']=round((date.today()-df['last_credit_pull_d'])/np.timedelta64(1,'M'))
    df['nxt_pymnt_d']=round((date.today()-df['nxt_pymnt_d'])/np.timedelta64(1,'M'))

    df['lst_nxt_pymnt_diff']=df['last_pymnt_d']-df['nxt_pymnt_d']
    df['issue_lst_pymnt_diff']=df['issue_d']-df['nxt_pymnt_d']

    df.drop(['nxt_pymnt_d'],axis=1,inplace=True)

    input=np.asarray([[df['loan_amnt'],df['term'],df['issue_d'],df['total_pymnt'],df['total_rec_int'],df['late_recv_fee'],df['recoveries'],df['last_pymnt_d'],df['last_pymnt_amnt'],
                       df['last_credit_pull_d'],df['lst_nxt_pymnt_diff'],df['issue_lst_pymnt_diff']]])

    prediction=model.predict(input)
    if prediction==0:
        return render_template('index.html',prediction_texts='Borrower will repay the loan amount.')
    else:
        return render_template('index.html',prediction_texts='Borrower will fail to repay the loan amount.')
else:
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__=='main':
app.run(debug=True)
```

Complete traceback of error can be seen below.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Vikes\anaconda3\envs\loan_default\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 319, in run_wsgi xecute(self.server.app)
       File "C:\Users\Vikes\anaconda3\envs\loan_default\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 308, in execute application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
      File "C:\Users\Vikes\anaconda3\envs\loan_default\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2088, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\Vikes\anaconda3\envs\loan_default\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Vikes\anaconda3\envs\loan_default\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Vikes\anaconda3\envs\loan_default\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1515, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Vikes\anaconda3\envs\loan_default\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Vikes\anaconda3\envs\loan_default\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "D:\Study material\Datasets\Python Project - Bank Lending\app.py", line 50, in predict
    prediction=model.predict(input)
  File "C:\Users\Vikes\anaconda3\envs\loan_default\Lib\site-packages\xgboost\sklearn.py", line 1209, in predict
    class_probs = super().predict(
  File "C:\Users\Vikes\anaconda3\envs\loan_default\Lib\site-packages\xgboost\sklearn.py", line 818, in predict
    if self._can_use_inplace_predict():
  File "C:\Users\Vikes\anaconda3\envs\loan_default\Lib\site-packages\xgboost\sklearn.py", line 758, in _can_use_inplace_predict
    params = self.get_params()
  File "C:\Users\Vikes\anaconda3\envs\loan_default\Lib\site-packages\xgboost\sklearn.py", line 438, in get_params
    params = super().get_params(deep)
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'get_params'
```

You can find the complete, code https://github.com/Vikeshkr-DSP/Loan_Default_Prediction

Comment: Do you have a full traceback of the exception you're getting? Because the exception message by itself doesn't tell you anything about which part of your code the exception comes from. The traceback should have that information.

Comment: The error is in line no 50 (prediction=model.predict(input)) where I'm doing the prediction. Complete traceback of error is too long but the main error is AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'get_params'

Comment: Please [edit] the question to give the traceback, even if it's long. That error is meanless by itself because we don't know where `super` is being called from. The code you've given us is not self contained, we can't run it ourselves, so we're extremely reliant on you to provide as much debugging details as you can.

Comment: complete traceback for the error is added.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. The issue seems to be related to the value `model` that you're unpickling from somewhere. Can you tell us anything about that object? How did you create it originally? Can you share some of the code defining it?

Comment: Model is just a pickle of the XGBoost model which is trained on 12 features that can be checked [here](https://github.com/Vikeshkr-DSP/Loan_Default_Prediction/blob/main/Loan%20Default%20Prediction.ipynb). Pickled model starts from cell 192.

Answer (score 8):

Try adding scikit-learn to your requirements.txt

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: scikit-learn is included in requirements .txt

Comment: it solve my problems.

Comment: i had a similar problem. But I had to uninstall scikit-learn and then reinstall it. I do not understand what kind of voodoo is behind this. The weird thing is, that without install/uninstall it works in jupyter but not with python from command line

Answer (score 4):

I faced similar issue in my Flask application while using the xgboost predict function.

After installing the scikit-learn package the issue got resolved

`pip install scikit-learn`

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue in my Fastapi application while using the xgboost predict function.

Try to  install scikit-learn